# material disappears from game object unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have a really strange problem that I can't find the solution for. I am new to Unity and only had about a week experience with Vuforia. My problem is that I have a target which I am overlaying with a 3D object and then I compile to Android. My phone is a Galaxy S7. When I come up close and the target is detected everything is fine however as soon as I start backing out the material slowly disappears off of the game object. This only happens on my phone. I tested with 4 other phones (ZTE Blade, Pixel 1 & 2, HTC ONE) on which it works perfectly fine.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Images:

Close-up:
[Initial state, close up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hviYw.jpg)

Starting to back out:
[Material starts to disappear, seems like an invisible sphere around it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48cRN.jpg)

Material disappeared off of the object:
[Material is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjXC4.jpg)

Comment: That's very odd. Can you show the material properties inspector?

Comment: Select the material in Unity, In the inspector tab scroll down and uncheck the Reflections checkbox.

Comment: I tried the suggestion Hristo, it didn't make a difference...